# Incremental file for DBInputTable - how to create?

Tags: etl, gooddata

I have just read http://developer.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/incremental-reading.html about incremental reading but I don't know still how to create the required incremental file. I am able to set incremental key, but where is the incremental file, how to create it?

Thank you very much!

Petr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new file like "key.txt" in your Project folder and then go to the Reader component settings and select this file to be Incremental File. You have to first fill in the initial value, for example:

'IncrementalFile.txt' content:

`key = -1`

Then you are able to setup the Reader Component to following:

**incrementalFile**="IncrementalFile.txt"
**incrementalKey**="key=max(employee_id)"
**sqlQuery**="select * from employee where employee_id>#key"

Let me know if you have any problem with it. Once set up the Incremental key should be automatically updated after each run.

Thanks,

JT

Comment: This works for me locally, however will the "IncrementalFile.txt" automatically upload to GoodData and update when running from the GoodData servers?  Also, if the file is managed by GoodData, by uploading a new version of the CloudConnect project to GoodData, will that overwrite the values that are currently stored there?

Comment: You are true. The best way would be to put (backup) the file to some persistent storage. For example Amazon S3 or similar and map the file to this destination after each run and copy this file to your Project structure in the beginning of each run.. So it won't be changed after data loading process re-deploy.